# TFS Confluence integration, or alternative

Tags: tfs, confluence, requirements

We will probably be using Team Foundation Server (TFS). However, I see that it misses the agility of Confluence for managing requirements documentation, and I do not see SharePoint being close as good.

My question is, is it possible to integrate TFS with Confluence, in the same way Confluence integrates to JIRA? Or is there some other viable alternative to managing requirements other than Confluence that would integrate with TFS? To my knowledge, TFS Work Items aren't really a good fit for requirements documentation (other than short scenarios).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Details? what version of TFS? What version of confluence? Hosted or VM?If you use the Git repos in the newer TFS im sure theres an easy way.

Comment: TFS 2013 or 2015. Haven't decided on version control or hosting. My question is rather that I like Confluence, but I'm unsure if TFS can provide this type of service, or if there are alternatives. I'm not sure how Git affects this.

Comment: More effort in research required then.

Answer (score 1):

Using TFS 2015 you can see and Markdown files directly in the browser resulting in a Wiki experience. You can explore this feature in Visual Studio Online and see if it fits your needs.